# How to Trigger Anchor link using Javascript\Jquery using "<Section> tag ID"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

How to Trigger Anchor link using Javascript\Jquery using " ID" ?

```
<section id="myID" class="ccontainer None cmo1 ">
    <div class="cimage clearfix ">
        <a class="modal" href="/SOME_URL/index.jsp">
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what do you mean by using ID ? I don't see any url on your code.

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to do

Comment: ID  section tag id.. and URL is in href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
window.location.href = '#myID'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work...

```
$('#myID a')[0].click()
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you have provided, if you are trying to trigger a click event on the anchor you have inside that section and div, you can do this,

```
$('#myID .cimage a')[0].click();
```

That is to say, the 1st anchor inside class "cimage" which in again inside an element with id "myID".